# How to create an endpoint for a ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

**models.py**

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)

class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

class PublicationSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Publication
        fields = ('title', 'pub_date', 'author')
```

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'authors', views.AuthorViewSet)
router.register(r'publications', views.PublicationViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

**views.py**

```
class AuthorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Author.objects.all().order_by('-first_name')
    serializer_class = AuthorSerializer

class PublicationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Publication.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PublicationSerializer
```

**What I want**

As you can see, my two models (Author and Publication) are connected with a many to many relationship. What I want is be able to access all the publications of a specific author when I go to `api/authors/[id]/publications`. How can I do that?

Comment: `Publication.objects.filter(author__id=<id>)`

Comment: Please be more specific. Where do I put that code? What else do I have to add to make it work?

Comment: On your API view, your function is probably something like `def viewFunc(request, author_id)`. You'll want to do that query, which will return a list of all of the publications that author has contributed to.

Comment: Actually I only have two classes in my views.py file. I edited my message to show the content. How can I adapt my code to use yours with a function?

Comment: Looks like you should be able to write a custom `list` function to return the results you want: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

Comment: I need a demonstration with my code, I really don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you have solved this yet. But it sounds a lot like serializer relations found [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) in the DRF docs particularly nested relationships. Long story short, you would have something along these lines in your serilizers:

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.HyperLinkedSerializer):
    publications = PublicationSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('...', 'publications',)
```

Let me know if it works.